# C Regex Not Matching

Tags: c, regex

I've tested the following regular expression at http://www.regexpal.com/

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)+([_]{1}([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)+)+[.][a-z]+
```

Which successfully matches the following file names:

```
Butter_Butter.jpg    
JavaPiebald_Java_Piebald.jpg       
LowWhitePied_Pied.jpg  
Piebald_Piebald.jpg  
SpinnerBlast_Spider_Pinstripe_Pastel.jpg
Caramel_Caramel.jpg  
LightningPied_Pied_Axanthic.jpg  
Pastel_Pastel.jpg      
Spider_Spider.jpg    
Spinner_Spider_Pinstripe.jpg
```

When I implement the regular expression in the following *C* code, I receive no matches:

```
#define COLLECTION_REGEX "([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)+([_]{1}([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)+)+[.][a-z]+"

int is_valid_filename(char *filename)
{
    regex_t regex;
    int i, match;
    char msgbuf[100];

    match = 1;
    i = regcomp(&regex, COLLECTION_REGEX, 0);

    if (i)
    {
            perror("Could not compile regex");
    }
    else
    {
            match = regexec(&regex, filename, 0, NULL, 0);

            if (!match)
            {
                    puts("Match");
            }
            else if (match == REG_NOMATCH)
            {
                    puts("No match");
            }
            else
            {
                    regerror(match, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                    puts(msgbuf);
            }
    }

    regfree(&regex);

    return match;
}
```

Subsequent execution:

```
./a.out 
No match
No match
No match
No match
No match
No match
No match
No match
No match
No match
```

The regular expression appears correct, I am uncertain as to why I am obtaining these results.

---

Output from GDB:

```
Breakpoint 1, is_valid_filename (filename=0x609050 "Piebald_Piebald.jpg") at crp-web-builder.c:76
76                      match = regexec(&regex, filename, 0, NULL, 0);
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
No match

Breakpoint 1, is_valid_filename (filename=0x609460 "LightningPied_Pied_Axanthic.jpg") at crp-web-builder.c:76
76                      match = regexec(&regex, filename, 0, NULL, 0);
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
No match

Breakpoint 1, is_valid_filename (filename=0x609870 "SpinnerBlast_Spider_Pinstripe_Pastel.jpg") at crp-web-builder.c:76
76                      match = regexec(&regex, filename, 0, NULL, 0);
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
No match
```

Comment: What regular expression matching library are you using?

Comment: You need to supply a non-zero argument to `reg_comp` to get ERE (extended regular expression) matching.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Jonathan Leffler. The line:

```
i = regcomp(&regex, COLLECTION_REGEX, 0);
```

Should be:

```
i = regcomp(&regex, COLLECTION_REGEX, REG_EXTENDED);
```